# How can i check if pop up is open or close on click of a button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In our Application the id's that are being generated for the data-role="popup" is dynamic .

So every item will have a unique ID as this case

transitionExample101
transitionExample201

On click of a button is it possible to check if any pop up is open or closed

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/109/

This is my  code

```
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
    <div class="myactivelabelsWrap">
         <h3>Item 1</h3>

        <ul>
            <li class="labellist">
                <div class="close"> <a href="#transitionExampleFirst" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline closestyle" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">First Pop Up</a>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
         <h3>Item 2</h3>

        <ul>
            <li class="labellist">
                <div class="close"> <a href="#transitionExampleSecond" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline closestyle" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">second Pop UP</a>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExampleFirst" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
         <h3>I Belong to First DIV</h3>

    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExampleSecond" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
         <h3>I Belong to Second DIV</h3>

    </div>

    <input type="button"   class="checkifpop" value="Check">
```

please let me know how to resolve this .

Comment: Can't you check for `ui-popup-active` class? .If any popup is open, it will have this class

Comment: @SandeepNayak , could you please let me know how to check this .

Comment: But the issue is, will you be able to click any button if the popup is open? Probably, you will have a modal, although transparent.

Comment: yes , i can click any buttons when pop up is  in open state

Comment: `if( $('.ui-popup-active').length ) { //popup is open }`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/L24fc4hr/

Comment: @Huangism I tried but it doesn't work when the popup is open http://jsfiddle.net/jyrkim/tdzfhzjy/110/  a bit strange, but it could have something to do with the jQuery Mobile library which is used with the Fiddle. I haven't used jQuery Mobile that much so that might work differently from what I'm use to with plain jQuery.

Comment: @jyrkim How did you test it? The check button cannot be clicked while the modal is up

Comment: @Huangism I guess you are right, because popup it's a modal popup. Sorry about my confusion :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code to check if popup is open

```js
$(document).on('click', '.checkifpop', function() {
    if(!$('.ui-popup-active').length)
        alert('not opened');
});
```

```css
.searchWrap {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    padding:20px;
}
.searchWrap .searchWrap-inner {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    position:relative;
}
.searchWrap .extip {
    font-size:12px;
}
.addrestList {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.addrestList ul {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    list-style:none;
}
.addrestList ul li {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    margin:0px;
    padding:20px 20px 10px 20px;
    list-style:none;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ddd;
}
.addrestList ul li .leftlable {
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
.addrestList ul li .leftlable .label-wrap {
    float: left;
}
.addrestList ul li .rightlable {
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    height:auto;
}
.addrestList ul li .rightlable .addrest-btn {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background:none;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius:30px;
    width:42px;
    height:42px;
    float:right;
    line-height: 54px;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ddd;
}
.addrestList ul li .rightlable .addrest-btn:before {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-size:30px;
}
.addrestList ul li .rightlable .addrest-btn-active {
    border:1px solid #46af7c !important;
    color:#46af7c !important;
}
/* My Active Labels Styles */
 .myactivelabelsWrap {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-bottom:20px;
}
.myactivelabelsWrap .ui-collapsible-heading {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
.myactivelabelsWrap .ui-collapsible-heading a {
    font-size:20px;
}
.myactivelabelsWrap .ui-collapsible {
    margin: 0px;
}
.ui-collapsible-content {
    border:0px !important;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.labellistUL .label-BtnWrap {
    padding:0 30px;
    margin-top: -9px;
    color:#d03e43;
}
.labellist {
    margin: 0px 30px !important;
    padding: 15px 0 !important;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6 !important;
    border-top:0px !important;
}
.labellist .leftlable {
    width:80%;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
}
.labellist .leftlable p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
.labellist .rightlable {
    width:auto;
    float:right;
    height:auto;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.labellist .leftlable .minOrder {
    opacity:0.7;
}
.labellist .leftlable .label-red {
    margin-top: 5px;
    float: left;
}
.labellistDisable {
    background:#f5f5f5;
}
.labellistDisable .leftlable {
    opacity:0.5;
}
.labellistDisable .rightlable a {
    font-size:24px;
}
.listview .label-BtnWrap {
    padding:0 30px;
}
.labelEditIcon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    color: #999 !important;
}
.popup_myactivelabels_content {
    font-size:20px;
}
.firstTimeTxt {
    font-size: 30px !important;
    padding: 20px 80px !important;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
    <div class="myactivelabelsWrap">
        <h3>Item 1</h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="labellist">
                <div class="close">
                    <a href="#transitionExampleFirst" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline closestyle" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">First Pop Up</a>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
         <h3>Item 2</h3>

        <ul>
            <li class="labellist">
                <div class="close"> <a href="#transitionExampleSecond" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline closestyle" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">second Pop UP</a>

                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExampleFirst" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
         <h3>I Belong to First DIV</h3>

    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="transitionExampleSecond" class="ui-content" data-theme="a">
         <h3>I Belong to Second DIV</h3>

    </div>
    
    <input type="button" class="checkifpop" value="Check">
```

Comment: sorry I have fix it :)

Comment: in case the pop up is open , how can i close it ??

Comment: But i dont know its id know .

Comment: I have given a way to get ID in my answer below. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.checkifpop', function(e)
{
   //console.log($('div.ui-popup-active'));
   var collection = $('div.ui-popup-active');// Get all open popups, if any


   $.each(collection, function(key,popup){

     //You can get ID of the Popup like this:
     //$(popup).attr('id')
     // alert($(popup).attr('id')); // handle each open popup
      if(You_want_to_close_popup){

         $('#'+popupID).popup('close');

      }


   });
});
```

In short, you can check if any element has `ui-popup-active` class.

If there is, then you have popup open.

Observe that, if popup is closed, it will have `ui-popup-hidden` class.

**To hide popup:**

```
$(POPUP_ID).popup('close');
```

**To open popup**

```
$(POPUP_ID).popup('open');
```

Comment: Thanks sandeep , inn case the popup is open , how can i close that ??

Comment: You can find ID...find that logic in my answer too

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to close any open popups, you don't need the id:

```
$('[data-role="popup"]').popup("close");
```

If you need the ID:

```
if ($(".ui-popup-active").length > 0)) {
    var id = $(".ui-popup-active").find('[data-role="popup"]').prop("id");
    $('[data-role="popup"]').popup("close");
}
```

jQuery Mobile will only allow a max of one active popup at a time.